# NameNotFoundException when calling a EJB in Weblogic 10.3

Tags: deployment, weblogic, ejb, workmanagers

First of all, I'd like to underline that I've already read other posts in StackOverflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618488/namenotfoundexception-when-calling-a-ejb-in-weblogic-10-3)) with similar questions, but unfortunately I didn't manage to solve this problem with the answers I saw on those posts. I have no intention to repost a question that has already been answered, so if that's the case, I apologize and I'd be thankful to whom points out where the solution is posted.

Here is my question:

I'm trying to deploy an EJB in WebLogic 10.3.2. The purpose is to use a specific `WorkManager` to execute work produced in the scope of this component.

With this in mind, I've set up a `WorkManager` (named `ResponseTimeReqClass-0`) on my WebLogic configuration, using the web-based interface (*Environment* > *Work Managers* > *New*). Here is a screenshot:

[image: http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/8607/screenshot0p.jpg]

Here is my session bean definition and descriptors:

**OrquestratorRemote.java**

```
package orquestrator;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface OrquestratorRemote {

    public void initOrquestrator();

}
```

**OrquestratorBean.java**

```
package orquestrator;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.siemens.ecustoms.orchestration.eCustomsOrchestrator;

@Stateless(name = "OrquestratorBean", mappedName = "OrquestratorBean") 
public class OrquestratorBean implements OrquestratorRemote {

    public void initOrquestrator(){
        eCustomsOrchestrator orquestrator = new eCustomsOrchestrator();
        orquestrator.run();
    }

}
```

**META-INF\ejb-jar.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ejb-jar xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'
         xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         metadata-complete='true'>

<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>OrquestradorEJB</ejb-name>
        <mapped-name>OrquestratorBean</mapped-name>
        <business-remote>orquestrator.OrquestratorRemote</business-remote>
        <ejb-class>orquestrator.OrquestratorBean</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>

<assembly-descriptor></assembly-descriptor>

</ejb-jar>
```

**META-INF\weblogic-ejb-jar.xml**

(I've placed work manager configuration in this file, as I've seen on a tutorial on the internet)

```
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
   xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90
   http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">

    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>OrquestratorBean</ejb-name> 
        <jndi-name>OrquestratorBean</jndi-name> 
        <dispatch-policy>ResponseTimeReqClass-0</dispatch-policy> 
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>

</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

I've compiled this into a JAR and deployed it on WebLogic, as a library shared by administrative server and all cluster nodes on my solution (it's in "Active" state).

---

As I've seen in several tutorials and examples, I'm using this code on my application, in order to call the bean:

```
InitialContext ic = null;
try {
    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
    ic = new InitialContext(env);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\n\t Didn't get InitialContext: "+e);
}
//
try {
    Object obj = ic.lookup("OrquestratorBean");
    OrquestratorRemote remote =(OrquestratorRemote)obj;
    System.out.println("\n\n\t++ Remote => "+ remote.getClass());
    System.out.println("\n\n\t++ initOrquestrator()");
    remote.initOrquestrator();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\t WorkManager Exception => "+ e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately, this don't work. It throws an exception on runtime, as follows:

> WorkManager Exception =>
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   Unable to resolve 'OrquestratorBean'.
>   Resolved '' [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   Unable to resolve 'OrquestratorBean'.
>   Resolved '']; remaining name
>   'OrquestratorBean'

After seeing this, I've even tried changing this line

```
Object obj = ic.lookup("OrquestratorBean");
```

to this:

```
Object obj = ic.lookup("OrquestratorBean#orquestrator.OrquestratorBean");
```

but the result was the same runtime exception.

Can anyone please help me detecting what am I doing wrong here? I'm having a bad time debugging this, as I don't know how to check out what may be causing this issue...

Thanks in advance for your patience and help.

Comment: Does it show "OrquestratorBean" in the Console > Server > JNDI Tree view?

Comment: @josek If you're referring to "Environment > Servers > Admin Server > General > View JNDI Tree", I don't notice any "OrquestratorBean" entry there. Is this the right place?

Answer (score 3):

Your EJB gets bound under the following JNDI name (when deployed as EJB module):

```
Object obj = ic.lookup("OrquestratorBean#orquestrator.OrquestratorRemote");
```

Note that I deployed your code (without the **weblogic-ejb-jar.xml**) as an EJB module, not as a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your mapped-name in ejb-jar.xml "Orquestrator" may be overriding the mappedName=OrquestratorBean setting of the Bean.
Have you tried ic.lookup for "Orquestrator" ?

Comment: @Shreeni Thanks for your reply. I changed the descriptor to "OrquestratorBean" (to comply with the naming used in the annotation), but it didn't change anything: I got the same runtime exception as before. I updated original post with this change.